# Need Help filtering SQLdatabase in VB.net...diffent filter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i need help in filtering data. i want to filter row and put it in a textbox and filter another row in another text box vb.

ex.

ID--------- Date -------- msg_num ------------ Message <<

10001 -- 01/01/2012 ------ msg1 ------------- Blah! Blah!

10002 -- 01/01/2012 ------ msg2 ------------- Please Help!

10003 -- 01/01/2012 ------ msg3 ------------- happy happy

10004 -- 01/01/2012 ------ msg4 ------------- i don't know

10005 -- 01/01/2012 ------ msg3 ------------- vvvvvvvvvvv

10006 -- 01/02/2012 ------ msg1 ------------- dasdasdad

10007 -- 01/02/2012 ------ msg2 ------------- qqqqqqqqqqq

10008 -- 01/02/2012 ------ msg3 ------------- eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

10009 -- 01/02/2012 ------ msg4 ------------- yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

10010 -- 01/02/2012 ------ msg3 ------------- zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

first i want to filter the date 01/01/2012

then filter 10004 and put it in Textbox1,

filter 10002 put it in Textbox2,

and filter 10005 to Textbox3

output:

Textbox1.text = "i don't know" 

Textbox2.text = "Please Help!" 

Textbox3.text = "vvvvvvvvvvv"

*Message its not fix its changable...

Comment: Please choose either VBA or VB., then correct your tags to include the database you are using and one or the other.

Comment: Is it MS access, sql, VB.net vb6, vba ?

Comment: im using sql server management studio for my database and VISUAL STUDIO 2010

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datasource is in a DataTable (named `dt`), this should get the job done:

```
    Dim dr As DataRow

    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Date = '01/01/2012'"
    For Each dr In dt.DefaultView.ToTable.Rows
        Select Case dr("ID")
            Case Is = 10004
                TextBox1.Text = dr("Message")
            Case Is = 10002
                TextBox2.Text = dr("Message")
            Case Is = 10005
                TextBox3.Text = dr("Message")
        End Select
    Next
```

Beyond that, your choice of `ID` to `TextBox` seems rather arbitrary. Why do you need that specific order? Also, are there other columns in the datasource that would order the ID's in that manner?